# Функция считывает символы и запоминает их в массив

Tags: c, массивы, строки, указатели, символы

Не могу решить задачу на тему "Символьные строки и строковые функции":

Нужно написать функцию,  которая загружает с устройства ввода 
очередные n символов (включая пробелы, символы табуляции и символы новой 
строки) и запоминает результаты в массиве,  адрес которого передается ей в ка­
честве аргумента.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LIM 100
#define SIZE 81

char * input(char * string[]);

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char arrStr[LIM][SIZE];

    input(arrStr);

    puts(arrStr);

    return 0;
}
char * input(char * string[])
{
    int ct = 0;
    while (ct < LIM && gets(string[ct]) != NULL)
        ct++;

    return *string;
}
```

А вообще по разному пробовал решить, компилятор все время выдает ошибку либо с возвращаемым значение, либо на неправильные аргументы в вызове функции.

Я уже просто запутался. Как передать аргумент на строку, которую можно инициализировать в функции при чем чтобы она после (\n) не завершала ввод.
Хотелось бы посмотреть пример этой функции и как объявлять аргументы строк на двумерные и тд. размеры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, что-то [вроде этого](http://ideone.com/9ptJeU) сойдет?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * get_n(char*s, int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        int sym = getc(stdin);
        if (sym == EOF) break;
        s[i] = sym;
    }
    s[i] = 0;
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char buf[20], *s;
    for(;;)
    {
        s = get_n(buf,10);
        if (s[0]) printf("10 symbols: [%s]\n",s);
        else break;
    }
}
```